# How does Go resolve module URLs

Tags: go

I know Go downloads packages using git from github.

You can install go module with `go get storj.io/uplink`, it will be installed under `~/go/src/storj.io/uplink` but the module's github url is : https://github.com/storj/uplink.

How does Go find the github URL and why it is not installed under `~/go/src/github.com/`?

Answer (score 0):

They're probably using a [Vanity Server](https://github.com/kare/vanity) that operates using [Remote Import Paths](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Remote_import_paths).

Comment: @danny, that just serves the documentation for any publicly available package and has nothing to do with go get. In fact, pkg.go.dev has to use go get in some form or another to generate the documentation from the source code.